# LinkedHashMap removeEldestEntry: How many elements are removed?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

`LinkedHashMap` looks brilliant to implement LRU Cache. It has some overheads in terms of linked list management and not thread safe but then it simplifies the implementation and I can take care of these in my code.

The question I have, which I don't find answer so far about is how many elements LinkedHashMap removes from the list if removeEldestEntry is implemented and put finds the list full.

Does it remove just one element? or some percentage of the total size. My concern is if it removes just one element to put new element then its a real performance issue. As I see the rehash operations are very costly.

Please someone suggest how it works and If I can manage these to be removed elements count using  InitialCapacity, LoadFactor or any other way.

Answer (score 4):

`LinkedHashMap` is good to implement the *most trivial* cache, but for more advanced requirements it's probably not ideal.

Returning `true` from `removeEldestEntry` will cause the *single, eldest entry* to be removed, there's no way to tweak this to multiple elements.

Maybe something like the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`CacheBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) [might be what you're looking for](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained#Applicability).

Answer (score 2):

> LinkedHashMap looks brilliant to implement LRU Cache. It has some overheads in terms of linked list management

This is true of all LRU caches.

> and not thread safe

You can use Collections.synchronizedMap()

> The question I have, which I don't find answer so far about is how many elements LinkedHashMap removes from the list if removeEldestEntry is implemented and put finds the list full.

It *removes the eldest entry*. I.e. one and only one.

From the source for LinkedHashMap

```
    if (removeEldestEntry(eldest)) {
        removeEntryForKey(eldest.key);
```

> My concern is if it removes just one element to put new element then its a real performance issue.

It isn't.

> As I see the rehash operations are very costly.

Rehashing only occurs when the capacity grows, not when an entry is removed.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, Peter for your replies, Then I don't use removeEldestEntry, instead I keep age of the elements in my cache elements and whenever my override put finds cache full, it removes some 20% of the oldest elements. Also I don't let get method return any element from the cache, which has already been expired.

Comment: Why not remove any element which has expired, as well as removing any element which you get which is expired. If you remove 20% you could remove elements which haven't expired.

Comment: True, And I am okay with removing not expired elements that way. as far as removing 1 exprired element is concerned, my get method does that and returns null to the caller.