# LinkedHashMap removeEldestEntry removing 2 elements?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I looked at this thread: [LinkedHashMap removeEldestEntry: How many elements are removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669149/linkedhashmap-removeeldestentry-how-many-elements-are-removed)

And it states that removeEldestEntry removes only 1 element. This makes sense to me, but when I debug through my code, it seems to be removing 2 elements. I'm not sure why.

```
public class LRUCache {
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> LRUMap;

    public LRUCache(int capacity) {
        LRUMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>() {
            @Override
            protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> eldest) {
                return LRUMap.size() > capacity;
            }
        };
    }

    public int get(int key) {
        if (LRUMap.containsKey(key)) {
            int val = LRUMap.remove(key);
            LRUMap.put(key,  val);
            return val;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void set(int key, int value) {
        LRUMap.put(key, value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        LRUCache c = new LRUCache(2);
        c.set(2,1);
        c.set(1,1);
        c.set(2,3);
        c.set(4,1);
    }
}
```

So you can see from this that it will insert: `(2,1)` and `(1,1)`. The next element is where things get messy. Because the key 2 already exists, it overwrites the `(2,1)` element with `(2,3)`. After this, when I insert `(4,1)`, I already have 2 elements, so it should remove the eldest entry: `(1,1)`. However, it removes both `(2,3)` and `(1,1)`, leaving me with only `(4,1)` in the Map.

Any ideas why? I assume this has something to do with the key being replaced and `(2,3)` being at the start of the list, like it is the eldest entry, even though it shouldn't be. But I'm still confused why it would remove 2 elements.

On a side note, it looks like it is storing the eldest element at the front of the `LinkedHashMap`, which would also give us a constant time removal of the eldest entry. Is this true?

Comment: No it doesn't remove `1,1`: https://ideone.com/WStVFc

Comment: Hmm you're right, my eclipse shows the same thing in the debugger now. Maybe something was buggy with my eclipse previously. Ok well thanks for verifying for me :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key behavioral feature of `LinkedHashMap` to understand is that the  `Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>` members of the map are organized to preserve **insertion order**, which answers the questions you have related to the ordering of the members within the `Map`. So if we walk through each line of code in your `main` method, we will see the following:

1. After `c.set(2,1)` the contents of `LRUMap` will be: `{2=1}`.
2. After `c.set(1,1)` the contents of `LRUMap` will be: `{2=1, 1=1}`.
3. After `c.set(2,3)` the contents of `LRUMap` will be: `{2=3, 1=1}`. This action simply updates the value mapped for the key (`2`) from `1` to `3` and is *not* considered to be a structural change, so the order of the members is maintained.
4. After `c.set(4,1)` the contents of `LRUMap` will be: `{1=1, 4=1}`. The mapping: `2=3` is considered to be the eldest entry, so it is removed (and the mapping: `1=1` is retained).

Since it is clear from your intent that you want to create a **least-recently-used** cache, you should consider changing the construction of your `LinkedHashMap` to move away from *insertion-order* member storage in favor of *last-access* member ordering. The `LinkedHashMap` class provides an alternative constructor to support this type of usage:

```
public LinkedHashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean accessOrder)
```

If you pass the value: `true` for the `accessOrder` parameter, the member mappings will be stored in *access-order* (which is what you want to use for an LRU cache) or if you pass the value: `false` for the `accessOrder` parameter, the member mappings will be stored in *insertion-order*.